# Sending memory warning in applicationWillResignActive

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, appstore-approval

A few days ago I found a nice snippet on SO to test memory warnings by just sending a `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` notification every 10 seconds or so.

I really liked the idea and adopted it to only send out the notification when the app switches into the background, since it makes it easier to clean up some memory since every `UIViewController` listens to this notification anyway (and performs some memory cleaning that I also benefit from).

Since I'm a lazy programmer I wondered if this kind of trick is allowed by Apple or not.
Technically this not an private API usage and I even doubt that they find such things during testing, however, I'm not 100% sure about this. The code that I'm using looks like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Do some other stuff, unrelated to the question

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:application];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had done the same thing in my App iFerien Deluxe and it went through the approval process without any problems.
Personally I don't think, that this is a problem for Apple.
But in my current app I'm trying to avoid this, because it looks a bit hacky, as you better had to manually free your memory in applicationWillResignActive.

Comment: I do agree about the hacky part, but I came to the conclusion that it was a neat feature I could exploit to avoid writing custom code for every view controller (or writing a special super class for all view controllers).

Comment: I will give you the bounty once I can, which will be in ~22 hours!

Answer (score 0):

It may be *possible*, but it's a little bad form.

You could easily write your own notification. Just open your project's precompiled header file (usually under "Other Sources" or "Supporting Files" and make sure it includes this #define.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #define MyApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning @"myMemoryWarningString"
#endif
```

THe PCH is effectively included in every file you compile. Set up an NSTimer in applicationDidFInishLaunch:withOptions:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(sendMemoryNotification) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

in the sendMemoryNotification method, just post the notification

```
-(void)sendMemoryNotification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:MyApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Any class that holds significant data register as an observer for the key in the NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: I know how to send notifications, that wasn't the question. The question was about the built in notification which let the UIKit framework do all the work for me (including some work I can't do with public API)

Comment: I know that wasn't the question; I was only trying to provide an alternative, since sending system notifications yourself every 10 seconds sounds a little disingenuous.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, this was the original use case from the SO question I got the idea from. I just want to send it when my app goes into background mode to clean up some memory.

Comment: You could always register for UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, too.